# Deploying Service fabric project on azure cluster

Tags: azure, http, port, microservices, azure-service-fabric

I have created  a project with 2 microservices and had made then listen on two different ports but when i deploy them on Azure Cluster(remote) Only one microservice work which is at port 19080

Answer (score 0):

Have you opened the appropriate ports for the service in Azure?

Comment: Can you tell me how to do that?

Comment: You would need to login to the Azure portal and open the specific ports in the Azure load balancer.

Comment: Where can i find Azure Load Balancer

Comment: @user412144 see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-connect-and-communicate-with-services#connections-from-external-clients. The Load Balancer is created when you create the Cluster. It can be found in the portal as a separate resource.